# Access graph properties in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a Spotfire file and I am trying to automatically extract some info from its contents. I do not have any preferred way to do this, but I understand that IronPython is probably the way to go.

This is the furthest I got:

```
page = Document.Pages[0]
for vis in page.Visuals:
    print(vis.Title)
```

This outputs the title of all graphs/visuals. However, I am at a loss about how I could extract other info, like Graph type or x-axis title. I tried to find my way through the [API](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/Index.aspx?_ga=2.241848261.610112692.1500447944-1576752491.1493120605), but have been unsuccessful so far.

My Spotfire build version is 7.6.1.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to export your graph in an automated fashion or export the underyling data?

Comment: What I am trying to do for starters is to extract graph info (e.g. graph type, x-axis/y-axis title/expression). After that, table info (row and column names and expressions).